# setIdRevision() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\RevisionInfo or null, integer given,

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

im having a problem, im student of symfony 3.4, and i want to inster 3 new items on database with the id Relashionshiped of 1 element of other table but it is created, i need help because it display that error.
setIdRevision() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\RevisionInfo or null, integer given,

Thats is my code

```
            $chequeo = new RevisionChequeos(); 
            $chequeo->setidRevision($id);
            $chequeo->setOk($ok[$i]);
            $chequeo->setNok($nok[$i]);
            $chequeo->setSosp($sospechoso[$i]);
            $chequeo->setNum($num[$i] );
            $chequeo->setNombreChequeo($nombre1);
            $chequeo->setNa($na[$i]);
            $chequeo->setTexto($texto[$i] );
            $entityManager->persist($chequeo);
            $entityManager->flush();
```

$id is an int of value 3.

Comment: As the error says you need to pass an object to that method but not the id.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a object to the method, not a integer.

Short scratchup:

```
$info = new RevisionInfo();
// .. do something and fill the info

$chequeo = new RevisionChequeos(); 
// pass the whole object, doctrine is handling the saving of the relation by itself
$chequeo->setidRevision($info);
$chequeo->setOk($ok[$i]);
$chequeo->setNok($nok[$i]);
$chequeo->setSosp($sospechoso[$i]);
$chequeo->setNum($num[$i] );
$chequeo->setNombreChequeo($nombre1);
$chequeo->setNa($na[$i]);
$chequeo->setTexto($texto[$i]);

$entityManager->persist($chequeo);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Generally you should work with objects (when it comes to relations of entities).
The result is a integer in the column of course but that handles doctrine.

You give doctrine the object, it checks for the relation and column configuration and saves the entries correct (Foreign key construct in the database).